# Fourier Heat Conduction Law - why is temperature gradient negative?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

My question comes from the equation for Heat Conduction that I'm familiar with:

$$P_c = -\kappa A \frac{dT}{dx}$$

I'm okay with the logic behind this, except for the negative signature on the right hand side. I can't seem to understand why it's there. My lecture notes tell me this:

> We’ll also note that if we want κ to be a positive quantity, then we
>   also need to add a negative sign, as energy transfer due to
>   heating/cooling will go from hot to cold, i.e. in the direction along
>   which temperature is decreasing.

And from searching things up on Google and this forum, I can't seem to find anything yet that is satisfying to me. I realize that the direction of heat flow is from hot to cold, as heat *leaves* hot objects to cold objects, as is stated in the quote above, but I don't see how this justifies a negative on the right hand side.

Comment: Take hot at x=0, cold at x=1. $dT/dx$ is negative, yet heat flux is positive. You need the negative sign.

Comment: @JonCuster At $x=0$ does hot mean $T_{x=0} > T_{x=1}$? And why is heat flux positive, necessarily?

Comment: @JonCuster What if the derivative is zero? Heat flow would be zero but how is it possible if T is a maximum?

Answer (score 1):

Consider you have a bar whose length is L.

At $x_1=0$ , $T_1=100~\rm^\circ C$ and at $x_2=L$ ; $T_2=20~\rm^\circ C$.

When you try to calculate the heat flux density without the minus sign $\vec q =k\ \frac{T_2-T_1}{x_2-x_1}$
and this gives you something negative.
That's why we add the negative sign to obtain a positive value of the density.

Comment: the heat flux is not necessarily positive, with positive we mean in the same direction a x axis and vice versa.
in my eg. we know that the flux is in the same direction as x axis, but we still get negative (which means opposite direction) w/o the minus sign in the fourier law. that's why we add to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The minus sign indicates that spontaneous processes always tend to eliminate gradients (i.e., slopes). If a field (e.g., temperature) increases in one direction, then the associated flow (e.g., conductive heat transfer) will be in the other direction. This scenario arises throughout physics. We know that Fourier's Law is $$q=-k\frac{dT}{dx}$$

Here, the field is temperature, and the flow is thermal energy (more precisely, entropy, the [conjugate variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_variables_(thermodynamics)) to temperature). Temperature differences drive heat conduction and in turn tend to be suppressed through heat conduction.

In addition, Fick's Law of diffusion is $$J=-D\frac{dC}{dx}$$

Here, the field is concentration (representing an approximation to the chemical potential, the conjugate variable to the number of particles), and the flow is matter. Concentration differences drive diffusion and in turn tend to be suppressed through diffusion.

For electric charge, we have $$J=-\sigma\frac{dV}{dx}$$

Here, the field is voltage and the flow (different $J$ than before) is the current density. Voltage differences drive charge flow and in turn tend to be suppressed through charge flow.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "spontaneous processes always tend to eliminate gradients?" Eliminate gradients? What do you mean by that?

Comment: By "gradient" I mean a slope in any direction in an [intensive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties) parameter like a temperature, concentration, or voltage. Or more simply, the temperature in one place being different from the temperature in another place. As time goes by, these gradients tend to disappear.

Comment: And is that because of things getting into thermal equilibrium? And why exactly does the minus sign cause this elimination of gradients?

Comment: If the magnitude of something increases in the *x*-direction, and you shift some of it towards the opposite direction (i.e., the -*x*-direction), doesn't that tend to make the slope flatter?

Comment: Sure it does, but I just have trouble seeing the minus sign here as "shifting some of it towards the opposite direction". The temperature gradient, if is in one orientation and resembles some sort of line, has a negative sign attached to it, then I see it as reflecting over the $y$ axis.

Answer (score 0):

If you think of the transfer of heat from one body to another body as the transfer of water from a kettle to a  cup, then the rate which the water enters the cup must be equal to the rate which water leaves the kettle. The water volume in the kettle is falling and that in the cup is increasing. If after a time [t] the volume in kettle is [V2 ] having fallen from [V1] then the rate of change is V2-V1/t which is negative The rate of change of water in the cup is is increasing and, therefore, is positive. You can replace heat energy for water and the same line of reasoning will apply